# binary representation of a number without using bin() in python

Tags: python

I want to see the binary representation of a number using bitwise operations. I want the results to be byte-by-byte like this:

```
127: 0000001 0000000

1000: 0000111 1101000
```

What I tried so far:

```
b = bytes([])
while i:
  b += i & 0xFF
  i >>= 8
```

It didn't work because i & 0xFF is still integer. Integer can't be appended to bytes.

Comment: Looks like homework to me....

Comment: At the very least, you can simply use `b += bytes([i & 0xff])`.

Comment: oh that solves it... but is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

I followed @chepner comment.

```
b = b''
while i:
  b += bytes([i & 0xFF])
  i >>= 8
```